# "Browse other newsletters" needs to be changed to "Browse other community digests" in edit profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, newsletter

Recently Newsletters were renamed to Digests all over the Stack Exchange sites.

But in the [Edit Profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) of each site, when we are not yet subscribed to the digests, there are two buttons are displaying, where their description changed to **digests** from **newsletters**.

In DBA site's edit profile page, I didn't subscribe yet:

> [image: DBA]

But when we are already subscribed a site's digests and visiting to the edit profile, there I can see a single button and the button description as "Browse other newsletters".

I hope that needs to be changed to "Browse other community digests".

In Meta Stack Exchange site's edit profile page, I already subscribed:

> [image: MSE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops, missed that spot. The copy will be updated with the next production build.

Thanks for the report!