# Synonymize/merge [newsletter] into [community-digests]

Tags: discussion, meta, synonym-request, newsletter, community-digests

[Apparently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333622/295232), the newsletters have been renamed to [Community digests](https://stackexchange.com/digests). (I haven't seen an announcement or something.)

In my opinion, we should do the same for the [newsletter](/questions/tagged/newsletter) tag here. I have already created a new [community-digests](/questions/tagged/community-digests) tag; if the community agrees with me, can a ♦ moderator make [newsletter](/questions/tagged/newsletter) a synonym of it, or even merge them (which, according to the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70718/295232), should be done with all good synonyms)?

Comment: @Tinkeringbell This question has been open for 18 months. Any progress?

Answer (score 3):

I agree.  However, I think it would be a little easier to get a moderator of this site to merge the existing [newsletter](/questions/tagged/newsletter) into a new [community-newsletter](/questions/tagged/community-newsletter) tag, and just check the box to to keep [newsletter](/questions/tagged/newsletter) as a synonym.

Comment: Merging is fine with me as well, but I've always seen it as a 'final' stage for a synonym (see the FAQ which I now linked to).

Comment: @Glorfindel I often see it that way too, except when one of the tags to be merged is new, and what is effectively being done is a "rename leaving synonym".