# No confirmation after submitting edited closed question for reopen review

Tags: feature-request, review, edits, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

After I edited a closed [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374873/167867) of mine, I checked the checkbox, "This edit resolves the original close reason and the question should be considered for reopening." After clicking "Save edits", I was returned to the question page with no confirmation that the question was in the review queue.

Worse, because the "Reopen" link below the question had no vote count, it seemed like the checkbox to submit for review was ignored. That turned out not to be the case; I was able to click "Reopen" and add my vote. But that extra step was counterintuitive.

Suggestions for improvement:

- In the box describing the reason for closure, add a status line indicating that the question has been queued for reopen review.
- For users with permission to vote to reopen, when editing a closed question, on the checkbox to submit for review, have checking the box include voting to reopen (besides also submitting to the review queue). The checkbox text for those users would become something like this:

  > This edit resolves the original close reason. Vote for the question to be reopened.